# JSON string in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I'm new to Cordova and json and I've got what is probably a really stupid question.

I have an ajax call to a webservice and I end up with a string returned:

```
{"Table":[{"ProductID":189,"Product":"Product1"},{"ProductID":190,"Product":"Product2"},{"ProductID":191,"Product":"Product3"},{"ProductID":192,"Product":"Product4"}]}
```

My question is, how do I get this into a format that I can easily parse so that I can build the html to display on the page?

I have another section where I call an api and get back json but it has a tree structure rather than the string that I get back from my webservice.

Been banking my head against the wall all afternoon and am hoping someone can help and at the very least point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: `JSON.parse`? If it's already parsed, just use it like a normal JS object.

Comment: Thanks. :)
I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's already a JSON valid string. You can just use `var obj = JSON.parse(string)` and get back an object.

Comment: Thanks, this has sorted it.